# Formatting a string without knowing the underlying data type

Tags: c#, string, .net-3.5, formatting

I am binding data to a grid. Along with the data, accompanies the format pattern which is to be used to to format the data.

```
foreach (ColumnConfiguration colConfig in ColumnConfigDashboard)
  {
     int position = colConfig.Position + 2; 
     string format = colConfig.FormatData; //one of the undermentioned formats
     HtmlGenericControl lblColData = (e.Item.FindControl("lblBoundData_" + position.ToString())) as HtmlGenericControl;
     string data = drv.Row[colConfig.ColumnName].ToString();
     lblColData.InnerText = string.Format("{0:" + format + "}", data);
   }
```

The problem is while fetching the data, I am getting it as a string and have no way to know whether it was originally a `DateTime`, a `String`, a `Numeric` like `int/float/double` or something else altogether.

The format patterns as of now are (but will not be limited to)

> hhmm
>
> mm/dd/yyyy
>
> 24hrtime
>
> SSN
>
> {0} {1} {2} {3}
>
> {3}, {1}
>
> {1} {3} {2}
>
> XXX-XX-{5}{6}{7}{8}
>
> {1}
>
> d
>
> D
>
> t

Now some of these formats are recognized by the .NET framework (*like 'd', 'T', mm/dd/yyyy*) and some are custom (*like SSN*).

Is there a way to identify the base type of the data before the formatting or perform the formatting in a type agnostic manner?

Comment: Well, if it's all coming in as a string, how would you be able to discern truly ambiguous cases? Consider if the returned string value was "1000": is this `10am` ("hhmm" formatting) or the number one-thousand ("d" formatting)? I don't think it's _possible_ to discern _all_ cases. You might be able to guess for some based on special characters (like "mm/dd/yyyy", or the "XXX-XX-{5}{6}{7}{8}") but some will simply be impossible to guess. I would say this requires a design change: perhaps you can store the data type in the database as well and report it along with the string value?

Comment: Or wait, maybe I misunderstood: if you have the _actual_ formatting patterns to use, then you can just check against that. `if (format == "hhmm") { dataType == typeof(DateTime); } else if (format == "SSN") { dataType = typeof(MyCustomSSNType); }` Unfortunately, it may be difficult to discern all cases even from this. For example with "d" formatting, is "1000" an integer or a double? Again, you might be able to guess at _some_ types, but there will still be ambiguous cases.

Comment: Yes there will be quite a few ambiguous cases. I was looking forward for a generic solution.

Comment: It's not pretty, and I wouldn't use it in high-use code, but you could use RegEx.IsMatch in if/else statements.